# How many temporary objects are created in this initialization?

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

I have this initialization:

```
const char* str = std::string("a").c_str();
```

How many temporary objects are created in this initialization?

Can `"a"` be considered an temp. object?

I know `std::string("a")` is a temp. object.

The result of `c_str()` is a object, `str` stores it. So it's not a temp. object, right?

Comment: the temporary `std::string` is the only temporary object, and and `str` is a dangling pointer after this

Comment: I thought that pointers were objects.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo They are. However, being a prvalue, the initializer is materialized as `str` , there isn't a temporary object.  There was one before C++17

Comment: Looks like prvalues [are no longer materialized](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/32ac0796318a35104f541f33c0ddec6c8c7f8081).

Comment: @wally Thanks wally. I feel a bit nostalgic for that term though.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo Pointer variables are real objects, 100% objects, you can take their address etc. Pointer values are values that don't have a well defined address, or a lifetime; like 2+2. What's the lifetime of 2+2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"a"` is a string literal of type `const char[2]`, so it is an object.

`std::string("a")` is a prvalue expression and is not a temporary object (yet).  When you call `c_str()` you materialize a temporary object and call `c_str()` on it getting a pointer to the data of a temporary object.

You then assign the address of the pointer to `str` so now `str` holds the address to a pointer to the data of a temporary object.  At the end of that full expression the materialized temporary object is destroyed invalidating a iterators/pointers/references to that temporaries data.

That means `str` now points to memory you no longer own and is called a dangling pointer.  Doing anything to it other that assigning it a different address is undefined behavior.

So you have 2 objects when it is all over.  A dangling pointer (`str`), and a string literal (`"a"`).

Answer (score -2):

There is only one. The string.

`"a"` is a literal, which type is `const char[]` of approriate size, it has a static storage. So, it's not a temporary for sure.

`str`, and a return value of `c_str()` are `const char` pointers as well.

No other object are created.

Comment: *"a" is a literal, with a `const char*` as a stroage. So it cannot be considered an object.* This is wrong.  A string literal is a lvalue `const char[N]` array, so it is an object.

Comment: @NathanOliver agree that's a object. But can it be considered temporary?

Comment: @JoãoPaulo No.  It will live for the life of the program.

Comment: @NathanOliver I stand corrected, regarding the type, but I am not sure if that a `const char` array can be considered an object.

Comment: @luk32 It is explicitly called one by the standard: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.string#15

Comment: @NathanOliver An object with no defined lifetime, never constructed or initialized.

Comment: "_So, it's not a temporary for sure_" It'd better be a temp. At least a temp would be initialized properly and have a lifetime.

Comment: @curiousguy What?  The standard says *object with static storage duration, initialized from the given characters as specified above*. So it has a defined lifetime (static objects live from their first encounter to the end of the program) and it is initialized.

Comment: @NathanOliver So it's an object and its lifetime starts when it's defined (no) dynamically created (with new, no) or as a temporary (no). It's not covered so it's UB. Technically and textually, not in real life.

Comment: @curiousguy Sorry but that is plain wrong.  If you want you can ask a Q and get a definite answer.  If using string literals was UB then basically all programs would be UB.  The string literal is the objects definition and the objects lifetime starts the first time the string literal is encountered.

Comment: @NathanOliver Obv. all programs have UB at least from MT ill defined semantics. I asked a Q about that which was closed as too broad (actually too disturbing and thought provoking). The idea that would believe that correct C++ program don't have UB according to textual std is quite funny.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The explanation lacked any substance, like a mantra repeated endlessly. Nobody was able to answer the central Q: how do you prove the validity of a program under MT semantics. The Q is so deep and problematic it was deleted! You can't define a semantic if you allow UB, by definition.

Answer (score -3):

> Can `"a"` be considered an temp. object?

Technically, *it not well defined*.

It does *not* have a defined lifetime. Technically using it does *not* has defined behavior. It is *not* of the construct that officially begins the lifetime of an object.

In practice you can use it (obviously).

Comment: Sorry for all the naysayers, it's true; there is nothing in the std that says the lifetime of `"a"` starts. Nothing. The literal, textual meaning is that it's UB to use the string, period.